# DynamoDBで部分一致させるには？

Tags: javascript, aws, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDBに `090--`, `080--` のような電話番号が登録されております。

下記のコードでは電話番号の完全一致は実現可能ですが、「090」「080」のみの部分一致でもDynamoDBから電話番号を取得する場合、どのようなコードを追加すれば実現可能でしょうか？

AmazonConnectの「問い合わせ属性を確認するブロック」では、result が true かどうかを条件に分岐しています。
Lambdaのコードでは、true(Boolean) で返していますが、問い合わせフローに戻った時点ではstringとして処理されています。
「問い合わせ属性を確認するブロック」でresult が 「090」「080」の部分一致の場合でも分岐させたいです。

部分一致では `return (item.PhoneNumber in phone);` を追記すれば良さそうなのですが、下記コードを追記しただけでは処理してくれませんでした。
「in」の追記以外にも何か追記するのでしょうか？

[image: DynamoDBの画像]

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "ap-southeast-2" });
const tableName = 'PhoneNumberTable';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // 発信者番号
    const phone = event.Details.ContactData.CustomerEndpoint.Address;
    // DynamoDBの一覧取得
    const db = await DynamoDB.scan({TableName: tableName}).promise();
    // 発信者番号が一覧に存在するかどうかの確認
    const result = db.Items.some( item => {
        return (item.PhoneNumber == phone);
        return (item.PhoneNumber in phone); // 追記箇所
    });
    return { result : result };
};
```

Comment: 質問文が書き換えられていたので確認です：DynamoDB では DynamoDB 側でフィルター処理ができます。フィルター処理を行わないのであれば毎回全件取得してくることになってしまい、データの増加に伴って線形に処理時間がかかるようになってしまうため、DynamoDB にデータを保存している意味が薄れてしまいます。このコメントが書かれている時点で質問文に書かれているコードでは DynamoDB 側ではなくクライアント側でフィルター処理をしようとなさっているように見えるのですが、本当にクライアント側でフィルター処理をしたいのでしょうか？

Comment: ご返信いただきありがとうございます。
DynamoDBでフィルター処理しても、フィルター結果のみ処理が可能でしたら問題ございません。
DynamoDBでフィルターしても、結果的には全件取得してしまい、意味がなくクライアント側のコードを取得するしかないかと思います

Comment: いいえ、DynamoDB でフィルターできるのであれば全件ではなくフィルターを通った一部の結果のみがクライアントに渡されます。このフィルターのやり方については回答 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/95233/19110 のとおりです。もしこのやり方だとまだ達成できないコトがあれば教えてください。その場合は自分が質問者さんの課題を正しく理解できていないのだと思います。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

設定したDynamoDBの画像を添付いたしました。

画像のように複数の電話番号からフィルターを実行して、
結果の一つの番号のみ分岐させる認識でよろしいでしょうか？
実施してみましたが、やはり正常に分岐されませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 最終的に `phone` と一致しているのかを見たいのであれば `phone` の内容を使ってフィルターすれば良さそうです。また質問文と違って例となるデータが `+813` 始まり（つまり日本の 03- 始まり）になっているのも気になっていて、`phone` として与えられるデータと形式はあっているでしょうか……。

Comment: ご返信、ありがとうございます。「090」「080」は参考という意味で「03」のみの部分一致でも同じことだと認識していました。こちらの参考サイトの内容は実現できておりますが、「090」「080」「03」など最初の電話番号のみで部分一致させて分岐させたいと考えております。https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/amazon-connect-phone-number/#toc-4

Comment: 先頭文字列の一致をなさりたいのか特定の電話番号がデータに存在することを調べたいのか、質問文とコードがちぐはぐになっています。つまるところどのような処理をなさいたいのでしょうか。先頭文字列の一致をするだけなら https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/95233/19110 のフィルターでもう達成できています。

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB の Query では key condition expression や filter expression が利用できます。`PhoneNumber` アトリビュートが primary key なのかどうかでどちらを利用するかが変わります。

どちらの expression も利用できる演算子はそう多くないですが、幸運にも `begins_with` はどちらでも利用できます。今回は「`080-` から始まる」と「`090-` から始まる」が使えるでしょう。

それぞれの expression の意味と具体的な実装については以下のドキュメントを参考にしてください：

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property